# File size is different in unix servers but count matches

Tags: linux, unix

I have a file in two servers like p01 and p11 ,both having same no of records but when i check the size both are different.

Can anyone please explain me why it is like???

Comment: is the file system identical on both systems? show results of `ls -l file`, `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: Compare the outputs of `od -c p01` and `od -c p02`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without access to the files but common discrepancies include:

- different character encoding
- different line endings
- different record size / padding
- BOMs